# ¿Hay alguna diferencia técnica entre estas dos opciones?

Tags: flutter, margin, padding

soy nuevo en el foro. Estoy aprendiendo flutter/dart y haciendo una práctica me ha surgido la duda del título. El resultado que obtengo al hacer la depuración en Chrome, visualmente, es el mismo, pero no sé si es preferible una opción a otra por algún motivo. Los fragmentos de código son los siguientes:

Opción 1:

```
class Pantalla extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Container(
        color: Colors.deepOrange,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(30),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Opción 2:

```
class Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.deepOrange,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: Pues no, al final puedes construir lo mismo con diferentes widgets, es más limpio la opción 1 ya que evitas anidar otro widget más.  Si quieres ver flutter en otro nivel, te recomiendo este canal www.youtube.com/diegoveloper

Comment: Gracias. Le echaré un vistazo al canal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo haría así:

```
class Pantalla extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Container(
        color: Colors.deepOrange,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(30),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Ya que son menos widgets, por lo que habría menos componentes que renderizar, visualmente hay muchas formas de hacer las cosas, pero en general, entre menos, mejor.

Ahora, el Margin y Padding, son cosas diferentes, revisa esta imagen, así como es en la Web, así mismo es en Flutter
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias Fernando. Un saludo.